# Update Clob over a db link

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, database-performance, clob, dblink

I am trying to update a clob column over a db link. Is there any best way to do it. Below is my sample code. Currently doing the below has a lot of performance impact.
Running gather stats also does not help much.
The db where the db link points to is an AWS RDS Standard edition.

```
UPDATE xx_table@rds_dblink
         SET finish_timestamp = SYSTIMESTAMP, 
             api_response = (SELECT api_response 
                               FROM xx_table_gtt 
                              WHERE api_log_id = g_log_id),
             response_code = p_response_code,
             status = CASE
                      WHEN p_response_code = 200
                      THEN
                        'Success'
                      WHEN p_response_code = 201
                      THEN
                        'Success'                        
                      ELSE
                        'Error'
                      END                          
       WHERE api_log_id = g_log_id
```

There is an unique index on the api_log_id column. API Response is a CLOB type.
xx_table_gtt: Is a global temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue about updating clob through dblink, finally my solution was to create bridge service(I have created service using java) between two databases and update clob through this service. It is an alternative solution, without using dblink.

Will be glad if I could help.

Comment: Thanks @Saidakmal. I wanted to have less number of hops while doing this update to prevent any breaks. Thanks for your inputs though :)